# Event Aggregator for Distributed Applications

Tags: prism, messaging, distributed-computing, eventaggregator, aggregator

I am implementing an application using Prism.
The application has a few distributed components that resides on various machines or servers. In order to communicate them, I am planning to implement messaging service using Event Aggregator. But before I start working on that I would like to have a few clarifications:

1. Can Event Aggregator be used on a distributed environment. If yes
   than how to define the server or hub where the message would be
   published or subscribed?
2. What is the performance impact on the applications using Event
   Aggregator? I feel it is negligible but still I would like to know.
3. Is Event Aggregator approach is good for future expansion in an
   enterprise environment?

Thanks and Regards,

Ashish Sharma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRISM is client-side technology. So, `EventAggregator` as it is won't do what you need. This is mechanism to communicate between modules in a loosely-coupled way. It is not about communicating between different clients.

For what you need - I would look into HTTP Polling Duplex
http://www.devproconnections.com/article/silverlight-40/using-http-polling-duplex-in-silverlight-applications

If you use PRISM on front end - you can write your own service and subscribe/publish EventAggregator events from that service while making server calls and receiving responses back.